# Could smoke allow arcs to form?

Tags: short-circuit, failure

I've been trying to find the cause of power supply failures, and noticed that an NTC is smoking if it runs at full power.  Obviously the NTC needs changing.  But is it possible that the smoke in the chassis could then allow an arc to form between 400 V traces or components when it wouldn't otherwise?  Either carbon particles on the PCB or ions in the smoke.

> Particles from cigarette smoke or smoke after a fire can land on electronics and can cause them to short circuit.

from [a dubious source](http://experts.merchantcircle.com/articles/How-Does-Smoke-Damage-Electronics/1004226)

(Or maybe it's possible, but components are designed with materials that won't have this effect?)

Answer (score 5):

Interesting problem. Smoke can conduct electricity.
From the research [here](http://www.osti.gov/bridge/purl.cover.jsp?purl=/3313-aqAnZ4/webviewable/) (first Google link btw.), "A surprising result was that the conductivity between parallel plates remained high although the optical density in the smoke chamber dropped drastically, indicating that there was very little smoke in the air."

The research also states that high voltages promote the growth of 'soot bridges', further strengthening the assumption that yes, smoke can cause arcs between high-voltage traces.

Comment: First Google result for what search?  I didn't find that paper in my searches.

Answer (score 5):

The issue isn't as much arcing thru air since even dense smoke is a tiny fraction of the overall air.  However, the smoke particles will settle and coat everything nearby.  This kind of smoke particle surface layer can definitely provide a easier path for arcing.

As dirt in general builds up, with smoke being another type of dirt, and especially at high humidity, the surface resistance of a PC board decreases dramatically.  The resulting leakage currents can cause problems if the board was not specifically desinged to deal with them.  For example, guard traces are one way this is dealt with in high impedance analog circuits.  You put a trace all around the high impedance one, which is then driven by a unity gain buffer.  Seen from the high impedance trace, the leakage resistance is now connected to nearly the same voltage as the trace itself, so very little current flows.  Little current thru the leakage resistance is the same in practice as a very high impedance to surrounding traces.

Answer (score 3):

First off, the NTC in a power supply should *never* be smoking. One of two things could be happening:

- the NTC is under-designed for the load current it's intended to carry (extremely unlikely)
- there's an NTC bypass circuit that's not working (most likely)

Most higher-power (100s of watts and up) power supplies use the NTC as an inrush limiter only, bypassing the NTC with a triac or a mechanical relay once the bulk capacitors are charged up (avoiding \$I^2 \times R\$ losses in the NTC).

If there is no bypass, the NTC must be rated to handle the maximum rated output current under the minimum rated input conditions without failing. Smoking != 'rated to handle'.

Tangental rant aside, when PCB layouts are evaulated for safety compliance, a 'pollution degree' factor is applied to determine the necessary creepages and clearances. A 'clean room' installation gives you pollution degree 1 (the smallest spacings), and stuff used outdoors or in especially nasty environments gets pollution degree 4 (the largest spacings).

Most office and information technology equipment (PCs, copiers, power supplies for office equipment, etc.) are certified under the '60950' standard, which uses pollution degree 2.

So yes, external factors like dust (especially toner dust) can and do influence safety spacings.

Comment: Can you give an example of a bypass circuit?  Ours is 400 W out and doesn't have one.  At 100 VAC input, the NTC will be at 141 VDC, and with 65% overall efficiency, will be drawing 615 W for a current of 4.4 A?  The component is rated for 6 A steady state, but I was overloading it.

Comment: [Ametherm](http://www.ametherm.com/inrush-current/inrush-current-faq.html) has a FAQ which touches on the idea of inrush element bypassing. A 6A-rated NTC shouldn't be smoking at 4.4A.